# Send ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello i have such code

```
<button onclick="sbt()" name="step1[save]" type="submit" class="btn-type5 next-btn-form pie" value="Далее">Send</button>
function sbt(){
var phone = document.getElementById('fld1').value;
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }}
        xmlhttp.open("GET","host.com/send.php?phone="+phone+"&t="+Date.now(),true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I want to send this request async, but when i use `xmlhttp.open(...,...,true)` this request doens't even go to server, i watch it in google chrome console, but if i run `sbt()` function from console request goes ok, and if i use `xmlhttp.open(...,...,false)` it works fine, can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the "How to return the response from an ajax call" question?

Comment: i don't need to get response i just need to send request.

Comment: Are you actually missing a quote before `host.com` or is that a copy/paste error?

Answer (score 2):

The submit button will immediately submit the form it is in, and the browser will leave the page (and the JavaScript execution environment from which the Ajax request is being made).

Cancel the default behaviour of the form submission when you want to use JavaScript instead.

```
onclick="sbt(); return false;"
```

(I'd look at using a [modern approach to event binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of `onclick` attributes though).

Comment: hm request goes to server, but it should go to another page after button click, but it stay on same page

Comment: The point of using Ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to go to a different one, then have the URL you submit the form to handle all the functionality instead of splitting it between multiple HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

is this your entire page code?

Have you checked the  jscript load order ?

please take a look at this---> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/8sBCn/3/) (this has a 3 sec response delay )

```
<h2>AJAX async demo</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="callAjax()">Request data</button>
<div id="testDiv"></div>

<script>
function callAjax() {

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/echo/html/", true);
    var params = "html=test&delay=3"
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
</script>
```